# Oracle - Looping Assignments in Table-Valued Function

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an interesting case here. I want to know if it is possible to do something like the following:

In a table-valued function, I need to run a query for every single "employer" individually and then concatenate the results into the table type being returned. I have simplified these results much more than my actual code, but know that I need to be looping for each and every "employer" individually due to the logic being implemented.

I wrote this, but this gives the error that l_VALID_EMPLOYEE_OBJ_TABLE does not exist:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE VALID_EMPLOYEE_OBJ_TABLE IS TABLE OF NVARCHAR2(50);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_VALID_EMPLOYEES
RETURN VALID_EMPLOYEE_OBJ_TABLE
IS l_VALID_EMPLOYEE_OBJ_TABLE VALID_EMPLOYEE_OBJ_TABLE:= VALID_EMPLOYEE_OBJ_TABLE();
BEGIN
FOR i IN (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYER_TABLE)
LOOP
INSERT INTO l_VALID_EMPLOYEE_OBJ_TABLE (SELECT EMPLOYEE FROM EMPLOYEE_TABLE WHERE EMPLOYER = i.EMPLOYER);
END LOOP;
RETURN l_VALID_EMPLOYEE_OBJ_TABLE;
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In a table-valued function, I need to run a query for every single "employer" individually and then concatenate the results into the table type being returned.

This is not normally good practice and will be very slow but ...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_VALID_EMPLOYEES
RETURN VALID_EMPLOYEE_OBJ_TABLE
IS 
  l_emps VALID_EMPLOYEE_OBJ_TABLE:= VALID_EMPLOYEE_OBJ_TABLE();
BEGIN
  FOR i IN (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYER_TABLE)
  LOOP
    l_emps.EXTEND(1);
    l_emps(l_emps.COUNT) := i.employee;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN l_emps;
END;
/
```

It would be much faster and simpler to use `BULK COLLECT`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_VALID_EMPLOYEES
RETURN VALID_EMPLOYEE_OBJ_TABLE
IS 
  l_emps VALID_EMPLOYEE_OBJ_TABLE;
BEGIN
  SELECT employee
  BULK COLLECT INTO l_emps
  FROM   EMPLOYER_TABLE;

  RETURN l_emps;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need a loop, and you don't `insert into` but `select into` that collection.

Sample data as I don't have your table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE employee_table
  2  AS
  3     SELECT ename
  4       FROM emp
  5      WHERE deptno = 10;

Table created.
```

Type:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE valid_employee_obj_table IS TABLE OF NVARCHAR2 (50);
  2  /

Type created.
```

Function:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_valid_employees
  2     RETURN valid_employee_obj_table
  3  IS
  4     l_valid_employee_obj_table  valid_employee_obj_table
  5                                    := valid_employee_obj_table ();
  6  BEGIN
  7     SELECT *
  8       BULK COLLECT INTO l_valid_employee_obj_table
  9       FROM employee_table;
 10
 11     RETURN l_valid_employee_obj_table;
 12  END;
 13  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE (get_valid_employees);

COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------
CLARK
KING
MILLER

SQL>
```